# Icinga2 check_load threshold on master node

Tags: configuration-files, icinga2

I'm having an issue locating where to change the thresholds for the check_load plugin on the Icinga2 master node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to redefine that command by adding the following to your commands.conf file in your conf.d directory. Add the following replacing `<load>` with whatever you want to call the command:

```
object CheckCommand "<load>" {
    import "plugin-check-command"
    command = [ PluginDir + "/check_load" ]
    timeout = 1m
    arguments += {
        "-c" = {
            description = "Exit with CRITICAL status if load average exceed CLOADn; the load average format is the same used by 'uptime' and 'w'"
            value = "$load_cload1$,$load_cload5$,$load_cload15$"
        }
        "-r" = {
            description = "Divide the load averages by the number of CPUs (when possible)"
            set_if = "$load_percpu$"
        }
        "-w" = {
            description = "Exit with WARNING status if load average exceeds WLOADn"
            value = "$load_wload1$,$load_wload5$,$load_wload15$"
        }
    }
    vars.load_cload1 = 10
    vars.load_cload15 = 4
    vars.load_cload5 = 6
    vars.load_percpu = false
    vars.load_wload1 = 5
    vars.load_wload15 = 3
    vars.load_wload5 = 4
}
```

The values you'll want to change are vars.load_cload1-15 and vars.wload1-15 or set them to varibles that you can set in the service definition with `$variablename$`.

Then in services.conf use the new name of your check command.